# use snow leopard server as LDAP intermediary between Google Apps and iOS (iPhone)?

Tags: macos, ldap, gmail-contacts

I have contacts on my iPhone which are sync to iCloud for backup purposes, and I use an iOS app "Contacts Sync For Gmail" to sync these to my personal Gmail account. I do this in such way, since the iOS app helps me preserve the labels, etc., rather than the Exchange feature of Google which is limited in that sense.

So, I also have a Google Apps account, and I will like to have these contacts (separate not mixed) in my iPhone, so that I can use, edit and add contacts which are related to my Google Apps account.

If anyone has a recommendation to accomplish this, please do so.

My question will be if it is possible to use a Mac Snow Leopard Server and through LDAP and some sort of sync app with Gmail (Google) or Address Book´s builtin sync function, to use the Mac as an intermediary between my Google App account and my iOS, and that way I can have my iPhone access the Mac server to pull and push.

Thanks,